Werewolf novel from the 80s or early 90s with silver fangs on the paperback cover
As a tween back in the late 80s/early 90s, I read a werewolf novel that, at the time, gripped me like no other story I had read before. I have long forgotten the important details but would love to read it again. Maybe someone can help me hunt it down.
This is all I remember:

The werewolf was a man in his 20s or 30s.

The was a new werewolf that was adjusting into the life and feeling a lot of guilt for enjoying being a werewolf. He looked forward to the slaughter, feasting, carnal sex and I believe raping of victims.

The book opens with a scene in which he's in wolf form swimming across a harbor or channel, perhaps to an island. It has a San Francisco vibe. Perhaps NYC.

The title was fairly short and succinct. Something like Silver Fang, Fang, Blood Fang, Bullet Moon or something like that. Don't let my keywords corrupt your brainstorming, though. It may have had an entirely different set of words in the title. I'm just illustrating how I remember it being short and succinct and MAYBE having similar wording.

The cover art was silver werewolf fangs.

I believe the author was a male.


That's it. That's all I remember.
But boy oh boy, if someone, somehow helps me find this book, I'll be over the moon.
Thank you!

The "Silver Fangs" is a tribe in the White Wolf RPG Werewolf: the Apocalypse. I checked the list of novels here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Werewolf:_The_Apocalypse_books#Novels), but none of them match the description.
Interestingly, the Silver Fangs Tribebook has stylized fangs on the cover, but that's an RPG supplement, rather than a novel. White Wolf did feature fiction in the Tribebooks, but it would have been a couple of pages long at most.

I believe the book you're looking for is Saint Peter's Wolf by Michael Cadnum (1991/93 pb). The description is below and the cover matches.
From the back of the book:

Collector Benjamin Byrd has added a new and eerie item to his archives: a set of fangs embedded in silver. As he grows more and more obsessed with his new treasure, he finds himself experiencing dreams and visionary adventures. Soon, Benjamin’s normal, successful routine is transformed beyond anything he ever imagined; he has to confront the truth that he is no longer simply human. This powerful and lyrical story brings into our own day-to-day lives the story of the werewolf.

From Goodreads:

The first half of this book seems to be a traditional “cursed object” werewolf story: repressed nebbish guy who collects antiques, creepy set of wolf like teeth set in silver with a sinister history, weird dreams, hideous night-time murders followed by the protagonist waking up naked in his back yard...

Cover:


Silver Bullet by Stephen King is the first one that came to mind, which was adapted from "Cycle of The Werewolf", but that's all I got.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this fits the question?  Does the opening scene match?

It's probably not this one. "Cycle of the Werewolf" has several pieces of colored art, which are pretty memorable. It would be difficult to remember the story without remembering the art as well.
